# Having 2 function in one onchange

Tags: javascript, php

How can i add return confirm in the onchange function? This is want i want to add return confirm('Are you sure?');

```
<select name='<?php echo "sel".$a; ?>' onchange='this.form.submit()' style='width: 150px'>
```

Comment: Try this way `onchange='confirm("Are your Sure?"); this.form.submit();'`

Answer (score 3):

Create a javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(form){
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            form.submit()
        }
        else{
            location.reload()
        }

    }
</script>
```

And then adjust your HTML to be:

```
<select name='<?php echo "sel".$a; ?>' onchange='submitForm(this.form)' style='width: 150px'>
```

Comment: Thanks for this man. What i want next is when i change the value in the select, and if i cancel, it will return the current value of the select.

Comment: @Jalo Creer that sounds like material for a new question to me as the original problem is solved, right?

Comment: How can i reload the page if i clicked on cancel?

Comment: Edited to reload the page if confirm is cancelled